# I am very very new to coding and i just have no idea why this piece of my code doesn't work

Tags: python, syntax

this piece of code works in the console i used to learn python on google but it doesn't work on the official python console (sorry if I'm missing something obvious) I was trying to create a piece of codde where I could have multiple tasks as variables and use comprehensions to only use some of them and have 0 meaning pending to be completed, 1 being completed, and 2 being installed. ( this is only a part of the code where there is a problem.

```
Task1 = 0

try:
    if Task1 == 0:
        print("Task1 = pending")
except:
    pass
```

I tried to follow what the console told me to do and eventually got to this until no matter what I did the syntax error thing wouldn't change

```
Task1 = 0

 try:
     if(Task1 == 0); print("Task1 = pending")
except:
    pass
```

Comment: `if` needs a colon not a semicolon in failing case. No exception is going to occur so the try/except/pass is extraneous.  Indentation is also wrong.

Comment: If there's a syntax error, it's not in that first code snippet. Either it's somewhere in the surrounding code, or you didn't reproduce your code accurately. (The second snippet has broken indentation and a semicolon that needs to be a colon, but the first snippet shows no syntax errors.)

Comment: @MarkTolonen So you edited the post and now first python snippet is syntactically correct in the post. Why?

Comment: @thanos-pakou All I added was missing code formatting markup.  The code is exactly as posted.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Well now it runs though haha. Not being hostile just curious cause in python an indentation is important and in this case when I saw the post, that was the whole issue.

Comment: @thanos-pakou If you paste code into SO all the lines run together unless code formatted.  The OP obviously didn't know this.  Look at the original **markup** of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code runs well in the REPL. In the second code, your if statement should end with a colon not semi-colon.

Also, you have some indentation errors. Your try-except block should be properly indented to avoid getting `IndentationErrors`. Effecting these fixes, your program should look like this:

```
Task1 = 0

try:
     if(Task1 == 0):
         print("Task1 = pending")
except:
    pass
```

See [Indentation Error in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-error-in-python/).